# inserting data into new table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

First of all I know php mysql_* functions are depreciated, but my supervisor wants me to use the regardless.

In this piece of code everything is running fine, except the line:  $insert =

```
  "insert into match (t_id, s_id) values ('$tutor_id', '$student_id')";
```

The data is printed out correctly using the line:

```
      echo  "<script>alert('$tutor_id, $student_id')</script>";
```

However the data still won't go into the table "match". I can't figure this out

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
    mysql_query($insert);

        $run_6  =   mysql_query("select tutors.tutor_id, students.student_id 
                            from tutors, students 
                            where tutor_availability = '$student_availability'
                            AND (tutor_subject_1 = '$student_subject_1'
                            OR tutor_subject_1 = '$student_subject_2'
                            OR tutor_subject_2 = '$student_subject_2'
                            OR tutor_subject_2 = '$student_subject_1')");

while($row = mysql_fetch_row($run_6)) {
    $tutor_id = $row[0];
    $student_id = $row[1];

     echo  "<script>alert('$tutor_id, $student_id')</script>";

    $insert = "insert into match (t_id, s_id) values ('$tutor_id', '$student_id')";

    mysql_query($insert);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`match` is a [reserved keyword](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysqld-version-reference/en/mysqld-version-reference-reservedwords-5-5.html). That means if you are going to name a table that you must wrap it in ticks:

```
insert into `match` (t_id, s_id) values ('$tutor_id', '$student_id')
```

This would have been brought to your attention if you had error checking and handling in your code. At the very least during development check `mysql_error()`.

Comment: Thank you, you legend. I should have put in these checks earlier, it would have saved me a lot of bother

Comment: I cannot agree more with @JohnConde comments on adding appropriate error handling to your code. This should be done ALWAYS, in ALL CASES when working with databases.  Check for and handle errors on server connection; check for and handle errors on DB selection; check for and handle errors on query execution; etc.

Comment: thanks guys, harsh lesson learned. for anyone checking this out in the future the 'match' didn't work, so I just changed the table name to "matches"